# Dynamic simple variable name and array name

Tags: php

I need some help. in my project i have two variables,

```
  $name = 'john';
  $reg = 10;
```

and from this information i want create a array named `$john10`  dynamically.
like

```
$john10 = new array();
```

so please help me.

Comment: It's not a good idea. Explain the original task so that we could help you to solve the issue in a correct way, not just helping you writing crap.

Comment: there is one file that call each time in my magento module and i need dynamic array names for it as i mentioned information above. i know data should be organized like key ($abc[1] = ......)  but here i can not use this type of logic

Comment: `$john[10] = ...` anything wrong with using real arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good idea to do this what you want.

If you need something like that name may have different value against different reg, then you can use a 2D array as like:

```
store[name][reg] = new array();
```

Hope you analyses that and I redesign your code.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would discourage doing anything like this in most circumstances, this is how you can do it:

```
<?php
$name = 'john';
$reg = 10;


${$name.$reg} = array();
```

Comment: "Although I would discourage doing anything like this in most circumstances" --- if you do, why not give a good advice?

Comment: Dear SO, I understand you all like reputation points, but **STOP GIVING SILLY ADVICES**. Thank you.

Comment: @zerkms To give proper advice on what to do instead of this construction, we'd have to know more about OP's situation. All we know is they want to concatenate 2 strings into a variable name.

Comment: OP asked, codefocus answered.  OP did not ask if is this not a good idea, and has been offered warnings and alternatives... Can someone explain WHY this is not a good idea rather than ONLY giving advice other than what OP asked?

Comment: @codefocus: right. That's why you need to ask OP about the real issue, not start answering blindly.

Comment: @Ryan: the thing is - OPs often ask wrong questions due their lack of knowledge. That's why you need to ask about the real task solved, because there is 146% chance that there is a proper solution for that. " Can someone explain WHY this is not a good idea" -- ask a separate question about that.

Comment: BTW, OP explicitly commented that he cannot use the alternative

Comment: @Ryan: "OP explicitly commented that he cannot use the alternative" --- it's not possible. It means that OP doesn't know that he can write proper code, not another messy one.

Comment: You did not ask him why he said that, nor explain WHY his request is bad practice. I don't think it's obvious

Comment: @Ryan: I asked OP about the real task, but he doesn't care. So he will use the terrible code that was provided in this answer. Instead of learning a person - you propose to feed them with the best practices.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40096/discussion-between-ryan-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 1):

Ok then you can use it though it is not best practice.

```
<?php
// The very top of your php script
$vars = get_defined_vars();

// Now do your stuff
$name = 'john';
$reg = 10;

// Get all the variables defined in current scope
$john10 = array_diff(get_defined_vars(),$vars);

print_r($john10);
?>
```